# Cumulative standard deviation of groups

Tags: pandas

How can one calculate cumulative standard deviation of groups with varying lengths?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo',
                             'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                       'B': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                             'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                       'C': np.random.randn(8),
                       'D': np.random.randn(8)})
```

`df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique()` gives bar: 2, foo: 3

...but...

`df.groupby('A')['C', 'D'].rolling(df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique(), min_periods=2).std()`

...gives...

> ValueError: window must be an integer

Comment: Would `df.groupby('A')['C', 'D'].rolling(2).std()` work for you?

Comment: No, because ['B'] is to be considered as the second level by which to calculate the cumulative standard deviation on in the group.

Comment: Could you give an example of how your desired output would look? At least in terms of structure.

Comment: ```row1: foo -> one -> nan, 
row2: foo -> one -> stdev of row1 and row2, 
row3: foo -> one -> stdev of row1, row2 and row3, 
    ...
row4: foo -> two -> nan, 
row5: foo -> two -> stdev of row4 and row5, 
    ...
row6: bar -> one -> nan, 
row7: bar -> one -> stdev of row6 and row7, 
    ...```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use `expanding` (new since Pandas 0.18) to get a rolling window that expands with the size of the group, first adding `B` as index and sorting:

```
df.set_index('B').sort_index().groupby(['A'])['C', 'D'].expanding(2).std()

                  C            D
A        B      
bar     one     NaN           NaN
        two     0.174318    0.039794
foo     one     NaN           NaN
        one     1.395085    1.364566
        three   1.010592    1.029694
        three   0.986744    0.957615
        two     0.854773    0.876763
        two     1.048024    0.807519
```